# Why would W'Kabi go against T'Challa?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, black-panther

What I found on the [Fandom Wiki](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/W%27Kabi) here about W'Kabi from *Black Panther*:

> Having lost his faith in his king due to his failure to capture
>   Ulysses Klaue, the man who was responsible for the death of his
>   parents, W'Kabi put his support in Erik Killmonger, allowing him to
>   take the throne of Wakanda and seemingly kill T'Challa as a result.

That doesn't make sense though. Yes, Killmonger confronted W'Kabi with Klaue's corpse but this should not be the persuasion that made him to go against his best friend T'Challa. I mean, although Killmonger is a half Wakandian, but he is not eligible to be ruler of Wakanda, neither his personality and the way he rules.  How could he put Wakanda in risk just because of his personal grievance?

Comment: Killmonger **is** eligible to rule as a member of the Royal Family

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Why would W'Kabi go against T'Challa?

Why not? His king failed to give him justice which this new king contender did. And it makes full sense from his perspective as he wanted justice for his parents and T'Challa and his father failed to give him that.

> But he is not eligible to be ruler of Wakanda

How come? He is of royal blood and he took part in the challenge like T'Challa.

> Neither his personality & the way he rules

How do we know how he will rule before being appointed? They met him recently and can't see the future and even T'Challa didn't have to go through any personality test.

> How could he put Wakanda in risk just because of his personal grievance?

Because that's is human nature, most of us do prefer ourselves before others and revenge does make people blind.